# Where is the data from NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate that was downloaded stored?

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession

So when I run this function

```
func run(u: String) {
    let URL = NSURL(string: u)
    let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
    let dtask = session.downloadTaskWithURL(URL!)
    dtask.resume()
}
```

I expect this method:

```
func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingToURL location: NSURL) {
    NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({
        let text = NSString(contentsOfURL: location, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
        println(text)
        self.done()
    })
}
```

to print the location of the file that was downloaded, but it always returns nil.

Shouldn't it return the actual path? even the `location` variable is always nil as well...

Comment: It is inside a folder called tmp, located inside the same parent folder as the documents folder. If you don't move the temporary file to the documents folder as soon as it finishes it will be immediately deleted ( it is a temporary file)

Comment: So when it reaches the ... didFinishDownloadingToURL location... method it is already deleted?

Comment: I usually save it using a completion block, so I don;t know if the problem is th addOperationBlock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingToURL location: NSURL) {
        let text = NSString(contentsOfURL: location, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
        println(text)
        self.done()
 )
```

Try code above

You have to save the data you download before this method `didFinishDownloadingToURL` return .

For example,you may use it in memory or move the tmp file to another dic.

If you use your code,when you excute your block,the method have returned.Because if you use addOperationwithBlock, it is an async block.It will return first,then excute the block.
So in your case,when you finished download,your method return first,then you excute block.So,you got nothing